# innerHTML from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to preserve Javascript context from an array. Is there any way to make this work? Or a more elegant way?

EXAMPLE:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

var arr = ["'There are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.'","'The other day I saw ' + i + ' pigs that one lake.'","'I can't believe there were ' + i + ' birds in your yard the other day.'","'Why were there ' + i + ' cats in my front yard?'","'There are ' + i + ' rabbits in the yard.'","'There are ' + i + ' snakes in the yard.'"];

document.getElementById('fudge').innerHTML = arr[rand];
</script>
<body>
<div id='fudge'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to do what? What does 'context' mean, in this case?

Comment: I'm trying to take javascript from the array and be able to use that code in the innerHTML… or an alert, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the outer double quotes.

```
var arr = [
    'There are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.',
    'There are ' + i + ' pigs in the yard.',
    'There are ' + i + ' birds in the yard.',
    'There are ' + i + ' cats in the yard.',
    'There are ' + i + ' rabbits in the yard.',
    'There are ' + i + ' snakes in the yard.'
];
```

***Update:** Also, place your `<script>` somewhere **below** the `fudge` element. Currently the script is running before `fudge` exists.*

---

If you want the strings to update with future updates to the variable, that won't work. You'd need to generate a new string.

You could make a function instead.

```
var animals = ['dogs','pigs','birds','cats','rabbits','snakes'];

function makeString() {
    var animal = animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)],
        qty = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    return "There are " + qty + " " + animal + " in the yard.";
}

makeString(); // "There are 3 dogs in the yard."
```

---

You could also take care of the singular/plural grammar value when the `qty` is `1`.

```
var animals = ['dog','pig','bird','cat','rabbit','snake'];

function makeString() {
    var animal = animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)],
        verb = 'is',
        qty = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    if (qty !== 1) {
        animal += 's';
        verb = 'are';
    }

    return "There " + verb + " " + qty + " " + animal + " in the yard.";
}

makeString(); // "There is 1 dog in the yard."
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use the variable `i` to create the strings, not just the letter `i`. As you use quotation marks around the strings, the variable isn't part of the string.

Instead of:

```
"'There are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.'"
```

just use:

```
'There are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.'
```

or:

```
"There are " + i + " dogs in the yard."
```